# How to fit the width of a v-data-table column to the width of a rotatet column header?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have to implement a pretty large data grid. The columns contain integers (up to 3 digits). The column headers are generally much wider than the integers. Therefore I rotate the headers by -90 degrees which is done via the "headers"-slot of v-data-table.

The code below is from the folowing pen: https://codepen.io/burgstjo/pen/ZVXqmQ

```html
    <v-data-table
        :headers="headersDataGrid"
        :items="dataGrid"
        >

        <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
            <tr>
                <th v-for="(header, index) in props.headers">
                    <p v-if="header.value === 'name'"
                        style="text-align: left">
                        {{ header.text}}
                    </p>
                    <p v-else 
                        style="height: 10px; text-align: left; transform: rotate(-90deg); transform-origin: left bottom">
                        {{ header.text }}
                    </p>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </template>

        <template slot="items" slot-scope="myprops">
            <td v-for="(header, index) in headersDataGrid">
            {{ myprops.item[header.value] }}
            </td>
        </template>

    </v-data-table>
```

Unfortunately the width of the column does not shrink. 
Another problem is that the height of the column headers remain to small.